# Find the value of $\ln\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)_{x=0}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $xy=e-e^y$ then find the value of $\ln\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)_{x=0}$.

I found out that $y+\frac{dy}{dx}x=-e^y\frac{dy}{dx}$
and also $2\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}x=-e^y\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}e^y$,or $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(x+e^y)=\frac{dy}{dx}\left(-e^y\frac{dy}{dx}-2\right).$
What to do next?

Comment: Well, if $x=0$ we must have $y=1$ from which you can read off the values of the deriviatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your first equation and solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to find $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y}{x+e^y}.$

Then differentiate again, using the quotient rule to find the second derivative in terms of $x,y$, and $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Substitute for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to find an expression for the second derivative in terms of $x,y$. At $x=0,e^y=e$, so the second derivative is $\frac{y(2-y)}{e^2}$. At $x=0$, we also know $y=1$, so the second derivative is $\frac{1}{e^2}$ whose $\ln$ is $-2$.